# How to get the Text of a Lexer Rule

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have a Antlr Grammar Lexer Rule Like this,

```
Letter
    :  '\u0024' | '\u005f'|
       '\u0041'..'\u005a' | '\u0061'..'\u007a' | 
       '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' | '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' | 
       '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' | '\u0100'..'\u1fff' | 
       '\u3040'..'\u318f' | '\u3300'..'\u337f' | 
       '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' | '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' | 
       '\uf900'..'\ufaff'
    ;

Name : Letter (Letter | '0'..'9' | '.' | '-')*;
```

I want to get the String Value of Name. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### from a parser rule:

```
rule
 : Name {String s = $Name.text; System.out.println(s);}
 ;
```

or

```
rule
 : n=Name {String s = $n.text; System.out.println(s);}
 ;
```

#### from the lexer rule itself:

```
Name 
 : Letter (Letter | '0'..'9' | '.' | '-')*
   {String s = $text; System.out.println(s);}
 ;
```